# Delete txt file based on keywords from multiple folders

Tags: pandas, file-read, edgar

I downloaded a bunch of 10-ks from edgar. I need to keep only 10-k reports with keywords "cryptocurrency" and "blockchain". Each company has one single folder. However, I was stuck on the reading txt file from multiple folders. Below are my coding:

Step 1 (this part works well and generate correct directories)

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = 'C:/test/2014/QTR1/'
words = ['cryptocurrency', 'blockchain']

filelist = os.listdir(path)

Path2 = []
for x in filelist:
    Path2.append(path + x+ '/')
print(Path2)
```

Step 2:

```
for i in Path2:
    filelist2 = os.listdir(i)
    for j in filelist2:
        if j.endswith('.txt'):
                
                each_file_content = open(j, 'r', encoding="utf-8").read()
                if not any(word in each_file_content for word in words):
                    os.unlink(j)
```

After running, Jupyter noticed me below errors:

> FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [43], in <cell line: 1>()
> 3 for j in filelist2:
> 4     if j.endswith('.txt'):
> ----> 6             each_file_content = open(j, 'r', encoding="utf-8").read()
> 7             if not any(word in each_file_content for word in words):
> 8                 os.unlink(j)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '0001000180-14-000019.txt'

Could anyone please help me revise the above coding or any other idea how to fulfill the task I mentioned? Thank you in advance!

I hope to delete files that do not contain the two keywords, any suggestions will be helpful!

Comment: Insufficient information. Please tell us how you generate variable `full_path`.

Comment: I detected an issue. The directory from "step 1" generated is not correct. My folder listed under "QTR1" are formed of firms' CIKs, i.e. (1800,2098,...etc.). The os.listdir() results are "100080,1000209,etc." Any thoughts why there has such an error? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pathlib (rglob recursive search):

```
from pathlib import Path


words = ["cryptocurrency", "blockchain"]
files = Path("C:/test/2014/QTR1/").rglob("*.txt")
for file in files:
    each_file_content = open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
    if any(word not in each_file_content for word in words):
        file.unlink()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Another question. I tested it, but found here is another issue. I want to keep a txt file that contains any word listed in words. They method you provide here will only keep those include both words.

Comment: change  any to all